# php & mysql search engine

Tags: mysql, search

i'm working on a search engine which search for data that user write in real time and i'm using this query

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE keyWords LIKE '%searchWord_1%' OR keyWords LIKE '%searchWord_2%' OR keyWords LIKE '%searchWord_3%' .....
```

is there any way i can select the question with the the best match, now if any of the 'searchWords' match any part of the 'keyWords' it will be selected.
how i can narrow the results, and increase the accuracy

thank you

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: This is a solved problem. As Alex says, use the fulltext-search index or something like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co).